# Query PHP variable against multiple MYSQL columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php variable called industry, what i want to do is query that variable against the mysql database.  However the mysql database has five columns in which that variable might be present, as indicated below.

industry   ------>    industry 1
                      industry 2
                      industry 3
                      industry 4
                      industry 5

below is my current php code.

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM data where listing = 'rec' and industry='$industry'";
```

is there a way to query my php variable against all of the columns called industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your line "industry 1 industry 2 industry 3 industry 4 industry 5" means that there are five columns, named "industry1" through "industry5".

In this case you can combine the checks with an `or` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM data where listing = 'rec' and (industry1='$industry' or
  industry2='$industry' or industry3='$industry' or
  industry4='$industry' or industry5='$industry')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to chain together the different possibilities in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM   DATA
WHERE  LISTING = 'REC'
       AND (    INDUSTRY_1 = '$INDUSTRY'
             OR INDUSTRY_2 = '$INDUSTRY'
             OR INDUSTRY_3 = '$INDUSTRY'
             OR INDUSTRY_4 = '$INDUSTRY'
             OR INDUSTRY_5 = '$INDUSTRY');
```